# Как обычно реализуется репликация tarantool с мастер-базой?

Tags: tarantool

Как я понимаю, часто tarantool используют рядом с основной базой данной (пусть для примера это будет mysql), например для кеша.

1. Как обычно в этом случае данные из mysql попадают в tarantool? Через код самого приложения (например, через php)? Или есть более красивый способ?
2. В Tarantool есть какой-то надежный официальный механизм репликации данных из mysql или postgresql в tarantool? Если есть, то можно ли управлять самой репликацией? Т.е., например, таблицы из mysql преобразовать в определенную структуру tarantool
3. Если всего этого нет, то предвидится ли? (Ведь всем вручную каждый раз прописывать перенос данных через код приложения видится мне не очень красивым решением)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть еще 2 способа кроме как из кода php приложения:

- когда клиенты читают и пишут в tarantool, а он сам ходит в основную базу по необходимости
- когда tarantool реплицирует данные из базы сам

Для первого варианта вам нужен [коннектор из tarantool в mysql](https://github.com/tarantool/mysql). Он позволяет делать запросы из Lua к внешней базе.

Для репликации из mysql мы умеем читать репликационные логи самого mysql и вставлять записи в tarantool. [Вот нужный вам модуль](https://github.com/tarantool/mysql-tarantool-replication).

Comment: 1) В обоих ссылках упоминается база данных mysql 5. А более свежая поддерживается?  
  
2) Модуль репликации из mysql  в tarantool выходит реплицирует в подобную структуру (т.е. отдельная таблица в отдельный space)...а есть какое-то решение, где можно задавать правила репликации?
Например, в mysql есть две таблицы: users и groups, а в tarantool они реплицируются в один space, где у каждого пользователя будут соответствующие группы.

Comment: Вот тут есть поддержка mysql 8: https://github.com/tarantool/libslave/pull/13. Но чтобы сделать готовый модуль, нужно будет собрать репликатор самому. Думаю через некоторое время мы это подтянем в master. Что касается разделения таблиц - то сам репликатор не поддерживает, но можно сделать на стороне тарантула через триггеры.